# How to delete files that are not open?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rm

Assume that there are three files in a directory of my Ubuntu-Linux. One of them is open in a music player, but two others are not open in any application and are not in use of any Process.

I want to delete those two files. In the other words, I want to detect files that are not used by any process, and then delete them.

I tried this:

```
rm !(lsof | grep "thePath")
```

but it failed. There are a problem with `lsof` here.

Is there any way?

Comment: You probably need `lsof` and `grep`.

Comment: I tried this: `rm !(lsof | grep "thePath")`. But it failed.There are a problem with `lsof` here. What shall I do?

Comment: Your task is to find a file that is being used, adding `rm` is obvious. I suggest you try and find out how your system can do that before applying the remove operation. I've seen questions posted that discuss but I am unable to test them currently.

Comment: You should post this kind of question on the [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) Stack-Exchange Website. Not here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is wildly wrong.  In the shell, unlike in many other programming languages, putting a command (as if it were a function call) in parentheses does not produce its result.

Instead, you want something like this:

```
for f in *; do
    fuser -s "$f" || rm "$f"
done
```

I preferred `fuser` over `lsof` as it allows you to query an individual file.

Comment: Maybe run `fuser *` without `-s` to see what else is keeping the files open? The output is a PID which you can look up from `/proc` or with `ps`.

Comment: Can you please explain the | | in your answer?

Comment: @jorfus It's a shorthand; `a || b` in longhand is `if ! a; then b; fi`. In other words, if `a` succeeds, we are done, otherwise also run `b`.